# VBA - Find max value for each category

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table of data in Excel and am trying to figure out how I can loop through the column taking the value associated with the max year. Then move onto the next property. Sample of the data is below:

[image]

What I'm trying to get to is below:

[image]

Not even quite sure where to start with this. I have tried looking for Max year but haven't been able to go again when I get to a new property name.

Thanks

```
Property    Year    Value
Apartment A 2013     64,516 
Apartment A 2015     92,805 
Apartment B 2018     9,426,984 
Apartment B 2018     12,569,312 
Apartment C 2018     160,061 
Apartment C 2019     161,882 
Apartment D 2018     281,979 
Apartment E 2016     -   
Apartment F 2017     1,875,000 
Apartment F 2018     2,062,500
```

Comment: is each apartment there only ones per year?

Comment: Also does it need to be vba?

Comment: Hi Lutz, yes its a sheet that somebody else created and has since moved on

Comment: Thanks Chris, I have tried to copy over in plain text

Comment: You can use a dictionary to collect the unique Properties; storing the year/value as an item; and replacing the year/value if the new value is greater than the old.

Answer (score 1):

Excel has the `maxifs` function. So if you copy paste the unique apartments to a new place you can use two `maxifs` to get what you want. E.g. Assuming property is in column A and you copied the unique properties to F:

```
     F     |       G           |    H
property   |   year            | value
Apartment A|=maxifs(B:B,A:A,F2)|=maxifs(C:C,A:A,F2,B:B,G2)
```